# providing a blank option in the combobox sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, dropdownbox

I am trying to populate a dropdownbox in SAPUI5 from a json

```
      new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox(this.createId('inpExpenseType'), {
                                selectedKey: '{ExpenseType/Id}',
                                editable: '{/CanEditPayment}',
                                required: "{/CanEditPayment}",
                                displaySecondaryValues: true,
                                items: {
                                    path: 'parameters>/Benefits',
                                    template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem(this.createId('liExpenseType'), {
                                        key: '{parameters>Id}',
                                        text: '{parameters>Name}',
                                        additionalText: '{parameters>Code}'
                                    })
                                },
                                layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: 'L6 M6 S6'})
                            }).attachChange(oms.app.ModelUtils.handleListItemChange)
```

Now based on a condition for eg. if(status==='Approved'), I wish to show only one option in the dropdownbox. I used the below filter to get this done.

```
    if(state==='Approved'){
//this is the option I wish to display in the dropdownbox.
        aFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Id", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "33"));
    }
    odropdownbox.bindItems('parameters>/Benefits', oTemplate, null, aFilters);
```

Now my problem is that this single option is getting defaulted in the dropdownbox so the onChange event would not be triggered.

I tried to default a blank item as below

```
   if(State==='Approved'){
        var oItem = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            key: 'dummy',
            text: '',
            additionalText: ''
        });
        odropdownbox.insertItem(oItem,0); 
        odropdownbox.setSelectedKey('dummy');
    }
```

But this does not make any difference and I see the single option populated as default.

How can I solve this? Is there some clean way to manipulate the json list?

Comment: Can you try `odropdownbox.setValue('')` ? that will set the value to none

Comment: No. Even that does not help. It is still defaulted to the single option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add the new item.

Use **fireChange** after you bind the items so that you have no issues.

```
odropdownbox.bindItems('parameters>/Benefits', oTemplate, null, aFilters);
odropdownbox.fireChange();
```

Comment: I already tried this . I am trying to access the items bound to the dropdownbox in the event handler. When I do the fireChange() it seems that getItems() returns a null value. So probably the event is fired even before the items have completed the binding. Is there some way to check if the binding is complete and then fire the event ?

Comment: Use jQuery deferred object .. You can do tasks after binding

Comment: There should be an event once the DropDownBox binding has finished loading items which I could not find. Now I do the firechange() as the first step in the next user action for this specific condition. This seems weird but seems to serve my purpose.